# Set the gravity scale to a certain value in a script

Tags: unity, c#

I'm using Unity Version 2020.3.18f1 and I'm making a hextris game (Tetris but each piece is 6 squares instead of 4). I'm trying to make the blocks fall using gravity, and I want to do this via code. I tried
`rigidbody2D.GravityScale`
but it didn't work. I got this error instead:

**'Component.rigidbody2D' is obsolete: 'Property rigidbody2D has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'**

I'm assuming that this means that the `rigidbody2D.GravityScale` is outdated. What can I use?

Comment: You need to use GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().GravityScale
If you want to affect the gravity for all objects in the scene, check this link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D-gravity.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm assuming that this means that the rigidbody2D.GravityScale is outdated

This is not a sound assumption. The error message does not mention `gravityScale` at all.

[You can consult the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-gravityScale.html) to find that the property is still supported, and is spelled `gravityScale` with a lowercase "g".

Your problem is what the error message tells you:

> `Component.rigidbody2D` is obsolete: Property `rigidbody2D` has been deprecated. Use `GetComponent()` instead. (UnityUpgradable)'

You likely have code that looks something like this (we have to guess because you did not include a minimal complete verifiable example in your question):

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

    void Update() {
        rigidbody2D.gravityScale = /* some expression */;
    }    
}
```

Note that nowhere in that class did we define a member named `rigidbody2D` - we're just assuming that one will already exist. That used to be the case in old versions of Unity, but not anymore, which is why the error message is telling you that referring to a `rigidbody2D` member that you have not defined is obsolete.

Instead, you should write something more like this:

```
public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

    // Declare a member variable to store the rigidbody.
    Rigidbody2D _body;

    void Start() {
        // Populate it with a valid rigidbody reference,
        // on start-up, or make it serialized and do it at edit time.
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update() {
        // Refer to the body variable you've actually declared.
        _body.gravityScale = /* some expression */;
    }    
}
```